# Herfindahl Hirschman Indices

Tags: regression, diversity

HH indices for a particular characteristics over units of observations
$i$ is defined as:
$$
HH=\sum_{i=1}^{N}s_{i}^{2}
$$
 where $s_{i}$ denotes the share of the observation in the total
of whatever the characteristic is. So, for instance, if we are considering
income by countries, $s_{i}$ would represent country $i$'s
share
in world income. This is a measure of inequality, as in a perfectly
distributed world, $HH$ would be $\frac{1}{N}$ which would tend
to 0 as $N$ increased. In a perfectly unequal world, it would be
$1$, as one unit would consist of the total. Now, I wish to run a
regression, say of ${HH}_{t}$ (or the HH index on time $T)$ on a particular
set of world characteristcs, call it $X_{Wt}$. The regression is:
$$
{HH}_{t}=\alpha+\beta X_{Wt}+\epsilon_{t}
$$
Now, in the above, the problem is that every year, the total number
of countries is changing. As such, for a given distribution, the $HH$
gets smaller just because $N$ is increasing. I was wondering how
to best account for this. Could one calculate, for instace:
$
\frac{HH_{t}}{N}
$
 where dividing by $N$ would account for changing number of countries?
Or explicitly account for it in a regression framework by including
the number of countries in the particular year:
$$
HH_{t}=\alpha+\beta X_{Wt}+\beta_{2}N_{t}+\epsilon_{t}
$$

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If your set of countries is changing over time, that seems a bigger source of bias than worrying about what the expectation is as a function of the number of countries. Fact is that most of the squared proportions will be near zero for most countries any way.

Comment: I can't account for the inaccurate meme that the person in question was called Hirschmann. It's not as if the person was obscure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_O._Hirschman